# Python regular expression with [:numeric:]

Tags: python, regex, bash

I am having some trouble with Python giving me a result I do not expect. Here is a sample code :

```
number = re.search(" [0-9] ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
print number.groups()

number = re.search(" [[:digit:]] ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
print number.groups()
```

In the first block I get an object returned but with nothing in it. Where I think I should get the string "2".

In the second block I don't even get an object, where I am expection the string "2".

While when I do this in bash everything looks fine :

```
echo "test test2 test_ 2 333" | grep " [[:digit:]] "
echo "test test2 test_ 2 333" | grep " [0-9] "
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The groups() method returns the capture groups. It does *not* return group 0, in case that's what you were expecting. Use parens to indicate capture groups. eg:

```
>>> number = re.search(" ([0-9]) ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
>>> print number.groups()
('2',)
```

For your second example, Python's re module doesn't recognize the "[:digit:]" syntax. Use `\d`. eg:

```
>>> number = re.search(r" (\d) ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
>>> print number.groups()
('2',)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the () which capture the contents for use with the groups() (and other) function(s).

```
number = re.search(" ([0-9]) ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
print number.groups()
```

This however won't work because python does not support the [[:number:]] notation

```
number = re.search(" ([[:digit:]]) ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
print number.groups()
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
>>> re.findall(r'([0-9])', "test test2 test_ 2 333")
['2', '2', '3', '3', '3']
```

Comment: That works perfect. And while I was waiting I kept working on it and discovered "re.finditer" which was working fine as well.

By the way, I just realised that POSIX character classes are not supported by Python.

Comment: Glad you figured the rest out!  The other answers are much more comprehensive.  (I was unexpectedly pulled away and didn't get a chance to elaborate.)

Comment: In fact, for The Greater Good, I would ask that you accept Laurence Gonsalves' answer instead (if that's even possible):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994178/python-regular-expression-with-numeric/994218#994218

Answer (score 1):

```
number = re.search(" [0-9] ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
print number.group(0)
```

groups() only returns groups 1 and up (a bit odd if you're used to other languages).

Answer (score 0):

.groups() returns values inside of matched parentheses.  This regex doesn't have any regions defined by parens so groups returns nothing.  You want:

> > > m = re.search(" ([0-9]) ", "test test2 test_ 2 333")
> > >       m.groups()
> > >       ('2',)

Comment: @adam:  great answer!  tip:  try highlighting your code and pressing ctrl-k to get your code to format properly, with syntax-highlighting.